# How to use remote app on local computer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote, remoteapp

Hi is there any way that I can use any remote app on my local computer Using `RDP`, `CLI`, `web browser` or in any other way, I don't want to access remote PC directly I just want to access the Application, so that the application display on my Local Computer for example to run `notepad.exe` in `windows 10 , 7, server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of some solutions which meets your description, but those are commercial solutions and might be complex/costly. One is citrix. This is name of the software and the company that produces it. Another is microsoft own Remote desktop service portal, where you publish your apps and they are made available to the end user by a browser URL.

Comment: is there any open source software.

Answer (score 0):

if it reaches out to interet you can proxy with apache or nginx. Also, you may have port forwarding on your router. Just port forward from the router to the computer & it's port. Probably best to lock down who can access those ports but much easier tahn using citrix.

However, reading your post you're looking for notepad.... So not really. not withot doing some sort of rremote connection.
That being said you could setup an ssh server on your computer and notepad ++  has a plugin that would allow you to connect to it and utilize it.

https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/07/27/how-to-edit-files-using-notepad-plus-plus-over-ssh-file-transfer-protocol/

Comment: hi `notepad` is just an example i want to run software's like `Matlab` and `Autocad`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run app on Linux (VSCode, Sublime Text 2, etc) or in WSL and output GUI to Windows workstation to X11Server in MobaXterm (run first and start X Server):

```
DISPLAY=192.168.1.10:0 vscode
```

replace you workstation IP. More: https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html